# Will the connections I have made to the root database in oracle 18c stop working if I enable HR user and XEPDBA1 database?

Tags: database, oracle

I am new to oracle databases and as the question says, I need to know if once I have unlocked the HR user and enabled the XEPDBA1 database, all the connections that I've made to the root database of Oracle, Will they continue working?

I've searched information about this on the internet but I haven't found something helpful.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your worries, because:

- is user's account is locked, you can't connect to it as you get

  > ORA-28000: the account is locked

  error
- when you unlock it, you're able to establish connection

Why would it affect other users in the database (I mean, their ability to establish connection)? Maybe I don't understand the problem, but I'd say that there won't be any problems when you unlock the HR user.